# Lucene/Solr - Query Analysis working, but Select handler not

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I have an issue with my solr settings. its NOT searching for "canaDa" in select handler as it is for "canada".

here is the schema for fieldtype `text_en_splitting` (they all are important):

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

.

Here is the solrconfig settings for select handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">20</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>

       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">court_id^0.1 jurisdiction^1.0 jur_code^0.5 court_name^1.5 court_code^0.5 court_type^1.0</str>
       <str name="mm">80%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="fl">*</str>
     </lst>
```

.

Here is the Query Analysis tool of solr admin:
[image]
.

As you can see, the Query Analysis did break it for "canaDa", but the search cant find it...

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing here is correct based on the way that the `text_en_splitting` fieldType is configured. With this configuration the only way that "canaDa" is going to match is if the indexed term is also "canaDa", b/c that way they will both be split into "cana" and "da". If you want "canaDa" to match "canada" then I would suggest you remove the `splitOnCaseChange=1` option in the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` as this is what is causing the issue here.

If removing the `splitOnCaseChange` setting is not an option, can you explain your requirements and expected behavior in more detail in the question so we can help you find a workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did see the `splitOnCaseChange=1` option, however, its quote useful. for e.g. someone could type "tradeMark" and it correctly finds "trade mark". further, I even tried preserveOriginal option..

Comment: The thing is that in the "Query Analysis tool" image I have attached, it does show that `WDF` created 3 tokens and `LCF` created the right token "canada". So why didnt it work in "/select"?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying now. I also missed the `preserveOriginal` setting and see that it is keeping "canada" in the list of terms as well. Thanks for the clarification. I think it is because you have `<str name="df">text</str>` set in your select handler. So it is searching in the text field by default. Try removing that setting and see if you start getting the expected result.

Comment: thanks for the reply... I also have this in my schema `<field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`. so text it automatically going to `en_splitting`